# Unit tests for NSOperationQueue with maxConcurrentOperationCount

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, nsoperationqueue, xctest

I have a class which is a kind of wrapper for `NSOperationQueue`. It allows to enqueue network requests using blocks. Currently the requests are executed one after another, but this can be changed in the future.

Here is the code of MyRequestsQueue class:

```
@interface MyRequestsQueue ()

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSOperationQueue* queue;

@end

@implementation MyRequestsQueue

-(instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(!self) {
        return nil;
    }

    self.queue = [[NSOperationQueue new] autorelease];
    self.queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;

    return self;
}

-(void)addRequestBlock:(void (^)())request
{
    NSBlockOperation* operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:request];
    [self.queue addOperation:operation];
}

@end
```

In general, I know how to unit test asynchronous code using XCTest. But now I want to add a unit test for `MyRequestsQueue` that checks if queue executes only one operation at the time. Or even better - test that number of currently executing operations is not greater than `maxConcurrentOperationCount`. I tried to observe `operationCount` property of `self.queue`, but the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOperationQueue/operationCount) says I shouldn't rely on it. How can I achieve it?

EDIT: My tests use the following pattern:

```
@interface MessageRequestQueueTest : XCTestCase

@property(nonatomic, strong) MessageRequestsQueue* reuqestQueue;
@property(nonatomic, assign) NSInteger finishedRequestsCounter;

@end
// setUp method ommited - simply initializes self.requestQueue


-(void)testAddedRequestIsExecuted
{
    [self.reuqestQueue.queue setSuspended:YES];

    __weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [self.reuqestQueue addRequestBlock:^{
        ++weakSelf.finishedRequestsCounter;
    } withName:kDummyRequestName];

    [self.reuqestQueue.queue setSuspended:NO];

    WAIT_WHILE(0 == self.finishedRequestsCounter, 0.1);
    XCTAssertEqual(self.finishedRequestsCounter, 1, @"request should be executed");
}
```

the WAIT_WHILE macro is from [AGAsyncTestHelper](https://github.com/hfossli/AGAsyncTestHelper).

Comment: Can you post your unit test method?

Comment: I added one of my unit test methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend rethinking your testing strategy.

> But now I want to add a unit test for MyRequestsQueue that checks if queue executes only one operation at the time. Or even better - test that number of currently executing operations is not greater than maxConcurrentOperationCount.

Both of these tests would be testing Apple's implementation of `NSOperationQueue`, which wouldn't gain you anything. You don't want to be unit testing code you don't own, and in general you should assume that Apple have correctly tested their own code. If `NSOperationQueue` ran more concurrent operations than it should, Apple would have a big problem!

Instead, I would simply test that after it's been initialized, your `MyRequestsQueue` has set the correct `maxConcurrentOperationCount` on its `NSOperationQueue`.

Comment: testing maxConcurrentOperationCount seems to be the simplest solution that works :) Maybe I was overthinking this.

Comment: I think it's important to try and weigh up the effort of testing particular functionality vs. how likely it is to cause a problem vs. how much benefit you'll gain from testing it. You should be able to safely assume that an `NSOperationQueue` will respect the `maxConcurrentOperationCount` you've set, so it won't benefit you to try and test that - just be confident you've set the value right in the first place :)

Answer (score 1):

Will it help? check the `count` property.

```
@interface MyRequestsQueue ()

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSOperationQueue* queue;
@property(assign) NSUInteger count ;

@end

@implementation MyRequestsQueue

-(instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(!self) {
        return nil;
    }

    self.queue = [[NSOperationQueue new] autorelease];
    self.queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;

    return self;
}

-(void)addRequestBlock:(void (^)())request
{
    NSBlockOperation* operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        ++self.count ;
        request() ;
        --self.count ;
    }] ;
    [self.queue addOperation:operation];
}

@end
```

Comment: Good idea. However, I don't know how to test that the value of self.count never exceeds 1.